# Swap 2 "Unique" values in a single transaction

Tags: apex, trigger, update, unique-field, enhancedlist

Scenario:

1. "User" Object has a field "UNEQ" which is setup as Unique.
2. Object "ABC" is adjusted in an Enhanced List View, which causes "User" to be adjusted via Triggered Apex.
3. The data in those records is unique to begin with, but we mixed 2 values in UNEQ field across 2 user records.
4. We need to swap those 2 values across those 2 user records.
5. Now of course we could change user 1 to be incorrect but still unique, then change user 2 to old user 1, and then fix user 1.  but this is 3 separate saves and mean while we have to break 1 user for a period of time.
6. Instead we want to use a list view and edit them both at the
   same time and press save, effectively swapping them both at the same
   time.
7. They are processed at the same time in Apex via a simple "Update UserList"

**e.g.**

- User Bob Jones with UNEQ__c = ROBJ
- User Robert Jones with UNEQ__c = BOBJ

this is incorrect data,
so with apex we have queried these 2 records - swap the values in UNEQ
and update it with a simple

```
update userlist;
```

it fails with:

```
09:39:17:232 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0050J000007MNPkQAO; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: UNEQ__c duplicates value on record with id: 0050J000007MNPu: []
```

IDs in this error and the ids of these 2 records.

**Is this possible to update them both at the same time?**

**I am getting a duplicate error** because they do seem to be saving individually and not at the same time.

I.E. the first record is swapped to the other but is being compared to the other and hence looks like a duplicate. Salesforce does not seem to realise that the other record is also going to change (meaning no dupe) even though it is a list update (Save).

FYI -There is trigger/apex involved, but I have debugged and can see the values are swapped in the list before the list is updated.

Current Thought:
**So it would appear the old value of the second record is getting in the way of the new value of the first record, during update DML of a list. Or this is specific to User Object. I am thinking the later because this situation does not occur on my source Object "ABC" which also has unique attributes that are being swapped.**

**UPDATE:**
**And yes I just proved "ABC" object can be swapped no problem**

**Is this just a User Object situation?**

Comment: My current solution will be to blank the values that interact like this and update them first to blank, and then update to the finished values.
This just requires more logic to manage this specific situation.

Comment: It would help to see the initial flow of details, code snippets, including the trigger context.

Comment: Phil, updated to add clarity.
code not needed to demostrate, the issue is not code, it is DML on the User object.
because the problem does not exist on Custom object.
The answer I provide is 1 way to resolve by manipulating the unique values and then updating again, this worked immediately and provides the fault.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not 100% sure, but I suspect there is a a different save process on User object causing each record to be saved one at a time.
Hopefully someone can reference an article to back this up.

this is what I did to fix it.

ultimately I blanked the users' Unique fields with

```
public static void updateUsers() {
    if(!preBlankUserMap.isEmpty()){
        update preBlankUserMap.values();
    }
    if(!updateUserMap.isEmpty()){
        update updateUserMap.values();
    }
}
```

before that I did the above I had to gather the correct data to pre blank with:

```
    for(User u : updateUserMap.values()){
        for(ABC__c abc : newABCs){
            if(abc.User__c != u.Id){
                if(abc.Code__c == u.UNEQ__c){
                    User newUser1 = new User(Id=u.Id,UNEQ__c='');
                    preBlankUserMap.put(newUser1.id, newUser1);
                    if(string.isNotBlank(abc.User__c)){
                        User newUser2 = new User(Id=abc.User__c,UNEQ__c='');
                        preBlankUserMap.put(newUser2.id, newUser2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your last piece of code looks problematic at scale if you can receive a lot of users and a lot of ABC__c records.

Comment: yes it is not designed to scale.
it is design to take records from a user entry, and the records are predetermined and limited.
I considered scale and scale was of no concern.

And actually it does scale reasonably well.
you should back up your statement about wht it does not scale, because so far it is the best way to work around the problem in the question.

Feel free to provide a better answer that allows it to scale better.

Comment: If we were integrating into this ABC__c object then yes scale would be of concern. and if we were I would be comfortable with its current form and apex's ability to forLoop.
it would still be the above questions challenge that is still the only concern.
worst case we now have an extra DML statement and twice the rows of DML.
So not sure your concern...